# My Batch File keeps looping, but why?

Tags: batch-file

I have written a batch file from a VB.NET program I'm creating.

When I double click on the file in Windows XP it brings up a Command Prompt and appears to be running over and over again.

My batch file is as follows

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Folder In Rename" /ve /t REG_SZ  /d "Open With Rename" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Folder In Rename\Command" /ve /t REG_SZ  /d "P:\Misc\Rename v2.0\Rename v2.0\bin\Debug\Rename v2.0.exe ""%1""" /f
EXIT
```

I can't understan what I've done wrong, but if I open a command prompt and run it from there, it runs once.

Any help would be gratly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any output?

Comment: Yes it just keeps repeating the following until I press Ctrl+C 
P:\Misc\Rename v2.0\Rename v2.0\bin\Debug>REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Folder In Rename" /ve /t REG_SZ  /d "Open With Rename" /f
it doesn't add the registry key either

Comment: Remove `EXIT` command. Check results again.

Comment: I initially created it without the `EXIT` command and it did the same thing

Comment: Makes no sense... Try putting some `ECHO Line 1` and `PAUSE` to check flow...

Comment: I guess: The name of your file is `REG.bat`?

Comment: Yes, it's called REG.bat, but I can change that to whatever I want if that'll help.
I tried putting in `ECHO Line 1` and `PAUSE` and I get
`P:\Misc\Rename v2.0\Rename v2.0\bin\Debug>echo Line 1
Line 1

P:\Misc\Rename v2.0\Rename v2.0\bin\Debug>pause
Press any key to continue . . .`
Then I press return and get
`P:\Misc\Rename v2.0\Rename v2.0\bin\Debug>REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Folder In Rename" /ve /t REG_SZ  /d "Open With Rename" /f`
and it loops around and starts again

Comment: jeb answered your question. You are attempting to execute REG.EXE via your PATH variable, but instead your batch is executing itself from the current directory. So, yes, change the name of your batch script.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `exit` in a batch file unless your intention is to exit the command processor. Exiting batch files is done with `exit /b` or `goto :eof`.

Answer (score 94):

In Windows, if you have a command line executable with the same name as your bat filename, and the batch file contains this command, the batch file keeps looping since Windows will execute that `.bat` file instead of the Windows command.

Example:

- Create the file `net.bat` on your desktop.
- In your file, write this text: `net`

Double-click the file, and it will keep looping.

The cause of this behaviour is the order of execution of the commands. The command you want to execute is in one of the folders in your path. But the batch file is in your current folder, so it gets executed first, causing the loop.

Comment: In Windows 7, this doesn't seem to be the case. Using the same script in Windows 10, I had the looping issue. This may be a Windows 10 feature.

Comment: Just tried this in Windows 7 and Windows 8 and the looping issue is there.

Comment: On Linux, this is considered a security risk. To run a file from the current directory, you have to specifically add `./` before the filename, or add the current directory `.` to the PATH. So why does Windows enable it by default?

Comment: Who would guess that! :-D

Comment: @wjandrea Discussing why Windows is flawed in many ways, and why Linux is better, is completely out of scope here.

Comment: @bsa That's not what I'm doing...? I'm asking about one specific design decision. But if the answer is "because whoever designed it didn't think about that", then fair enough. (Or for that matter, if it's a holdover from DOS that they kept for compatibility reasons.)

Answer (score 8):

make sure:

1. your script is not named like a build-in command or programm
2. make sure the scripts your script calls are not named like a build-in command or programm

e.g. if your script is called: reeeeeboooot.bat that calls shutdown -t 10 -r, but in the SAME FOLDER resides a shutdown.cmd

reeeeeboooot.bat will actually call shutdown.cmd INSTEAD of the build-in command.

sometimes the easiest things are the hardest. (pretty often actually :-D)

Answer (score 5):

In windows command line if you want to execute a command or a set of commands then we usually put those commands into a .bat file to execute them at any point of time but we must follow some guidelines before doing so.

1. The file Name and the command name should not be same else it would loop forever.
2. There should be no file in that directory having same name as the command name.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Terminal and DOS, to start a program, you only have to specify the filename without extension (such as `.bat`, `.exe`, `.cmd`, `.com`). Also, it is case-insensitive.

So if you create a batch file and execute `REG`, the system will first look in the current directory for something like `reg.exe` or `reg.bat` (or another executable with that name). Casing is ignored, so it will include `REG.exe`. If it doesn't find it, then it will look in the directories specified in the `%PATH%` environment variable.

In your case, you (assumingly) have an exetable named `reg.bat` in which you specify that it should call `REG`. So it will try to call itself, because it will first look in the current directory, in which it will find itself with that name.

The easiest fix is to use the full filename+extension instead. So you can simply change

`REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Folder In Rename" /ve /t REG_SZ  /d "Open With Rename" /f`

to

`REG.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Folder In Rename" /ve /t REG_SZ  /d "Open With Rename" /f`