# Shutdown via batch file into infinite loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, shutdown

**Problem:**

While running the batch file, it goes into infinite loop

**Code:**

```
shutdown -s -t 050
```

**Output:**

**Ran the batch file**
[image]

**Output when i run in normal batch file:**
[image]

**Output when i run in admin batch file:**

[image]

**Question:**
Now I wonder why this happens, and want to know how to run shutdown command normally from batch file, if not like this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Batch File keeps looping, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047442/my-batch-file-keeps-looping-but-why)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You called the batch file `shutdown`

Use a name that is not a system command or internal command.

Comment: Call it `Shutdown50.bat` for example.

Comment: Other than changing the batch file name, you could also edit it to instead run `shutdown.exe -s -t 050`, since it's not an internal shell command.

Comment: And here is detailed explanation this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434127/5882271